# Integrity constraint violation joining tables MySql

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have three tables recommends, products and products_photos. In recommends table and products_photos table, they both have product_id column. I want to join them(three) together but I'm getting this error `Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'product_id' in field list` , how can I join them?

```
Route::get('/info', function(){
$products = DB::table('recommends')
->leftJoin('products','recommends.product_id','products.id')
->join('products_photos','products_photos.product_id','products.id' 
)
->select('product_id','name','price', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
->groupBy('product_id','name','price')
->get();
//dd($products);

});
```

Comment: you have to specify table.fieldname in select or group by cluse

Comment: ->select('recommends.product_id','products.name','products.price')
->groupBy('recommends.product_id','products.name','products.price')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never specified the equality/inequality operator to be used in your join call.  Try doing that, and also qualify all columns you select with the appropriate alias:

```
Route::get('/info', function() {
    $products = DB::table('recommends AS r')
        ->leftJoin('products AS p', 'r.product_id', '=', 'p.id')
        ->join('products_photos AS pp', 'pp.product_id', '=', 'p.id')
        ->select('p.id', 'p.name', 'p.price', DB::raw('COUNT(*) AS total'))
        ->groupBy('p.id', 'p.name', 'p.price')
        ->get();
});
```

I assumes that `products` has the `id`, `name`, and `price` columns.

Comment: That gives an error `recommends r' doesn't exist` @Tim Biegeleisen

Comment: Sorry...apparently Laravel requires an explicit `AS` when aliasing tables.  Give the answer another try.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your Select statement You are selecting `product_id` which is available in both recommends and products when selecting such column you have to give table name from which you are going to fetch that column Like:

```
...
->select('recommends.product_id','name','price', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
...
```